# How to make CakePHP 1.2 work on PHP 5.5

Tags: php, ubuntu, cakephp

Recently i've moved to a new server, I'm running some websites which requires PHP 5.4+ only one of them requires PHP 5.2- which means that my hands are tied and not able to downgrade PHP Version, Thus, I really need to make CakePHP v1.2 work on PHP 5.5, I'd be glad if someone help me :)

Edit: Current status of app on php 5.5.9 is running blank page even with Debug enabled.

Comment: Did you clear cache?

Comment: No i did not, please explain why should i?

Comment: Cakephp 1.2 is built for PHP 5.3 and lower. There is no **easy** way to make it compatible for 5.5.9. Only thing you can do is turn on errors and debug and go through each error message and make the recommended change until the application will run. Potentially a massive job and the time could be spent better upgrading your code to cakephp 2.8. Check your php.ini to see if PHP error logging is on and the location of the log file. good luck

Comment: Your time would probably be better spent looking for a host that would allow you to continue running an older PHP version.